# How to remove strings from a list up to a certain character?

Tags: python

So i have a list containing this:

```py
list1= [ '[192.168.1.2] [Entered 123456] successful!' ,  '[192.168.1.1] [Entered 157] unwilling operator! ', '[192.168.1.3] [Entered 56]  not successful' ]
```

and i only need the list to have any strings up to the 2nd ']' and the list should look like this

```py
list1= [ '[192.168.1.2] [Entered 123456]', '[192.168.1.1] [Entered 157]', '[192.168.1.3] [Entered 56]']
```

do you have any tips what function should i use or a loop to use , because i tried to use the string index to output up to the 2nd ']' but the strings inside the list have different lengths.

also here is a sample of what i tried for the index that didnt work for me

```py
output_list = [word[0:30] for word in list1]
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  As @Manuel said, your supposed "list" is not legal Python syntax; it's so far off that we have no way to figure out what you have for input.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your given line of work is a cluster of syntax errors.

Comment: Im sorry i forgot to add the ' ' in the list elements , iadded it in so the list elements can be classified and i added what i tried on the indexing

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that to clarify the question. [**TIPS**]: Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using `Enter` everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on the square bracket and then slice up to it

eg.

```
for i in list1:
    res = i.split("]")[:2]
    print(res)
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it seems like you'd need to `']'.join(res)` to get the desired result.